# Iterate an array of dictionaries to get highest gpa

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Homework problem.
I need to iterate through an array of dictionaries to get the highest gpa and print the first and last name of the student. I'm having problems accessing the gpa field of the dictionary entries.

```
// Task 6
var highestGPA = 0.0
var students : [[String:Any]] =
    [["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Wilson", "gpa": 2.4],
     ["firstName": "Nancy", "lastName": "Smith", "gpa": 3.5],
     ["firstName": "Michael", "lastName": "Liu", "gpa": 3.1]]

for index in students   {
    if let val = (_,_,"gpa":key) {
        highestGPA = val
    }
}
```

Expected results would be that it iterates through the array of dictionaries and gets the highest gpa.
Actual result is a compilation error "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type (*,*,String) and Double.
So it seems it is getting the string "gpa" rather than the value of gpa

EDIT: I've also tried the following code to get the value in the "gpa" field and cast to a double.

```
for index in students   {
    myGPA = Double(index["gpa"])
    if myGPA > highestGPA   {
        highestGPA = myGPA
    }        
}
```

I get the compilation error: error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Any?)'
    myGPA = Double(index["gpa"])

Comment: Should should create some structs to store the people, instead of arrays. That way, you can have strongly typed members (gpa will be a `Double` that doesn't need constant `as! Double` force casting) and won't have to use strings to look up members (what if you make a typo?)

Comment: `if let myGPA = index["gpa"] as? Double {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have marked the values in your Dictionary as `Any`, when using it you must downcast it `as? Double`. The below code solves your problem.

```
var highestGpa = 0.0
var highestPerformingStudent = students[0]
for student in students {
    if let gpa = student["gpa"] as? Double {
        if (gpa > highestGpa) {
            highestGpa = gpa
            highestPerformingStudent = student
        }
    }
}

print(highestPerformingStudent)
// prints ["firstName": "Nancy", "lastName": "Smith", "gpa": 3.5]
```

Comment: You should avoid force-casting as much as possible. If a dictionary contains no `gpa` key, it'll crash the whole app.

Comment: +1 to what @EmilioPelaez said, force unwrapping is rarely a good advice, please don't recommend stuff like this to beginners.

Comment: This is what the teacher of the class recommended that we be doing.

Comment: @RossSatchell good to hear - do be careful of forced downcasting as mentioned by others. I edited the answer to demonstrate best practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Array` function `max` to determine to student with the highest GPA.

```
let student = students.max { $0["gpa"] as? Double ?? 0 < $1["gpa"] as? Double ?? 0 }

print(student?["firstName"]) // Nancy
print(student?["gpa"]) // 3.5
```

Comment: oops, should have tested in on playground first. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander suggested in the comments, you would be better served to define a `struct` to hold your student name and gpa data.  Then you will have strongly typed members and not have to cast `Any` to `String` and `Double`.  Structs automatically provide an initializer which takes each of the members.  This prevents you from making a typo when initializing your array of `Student` data.

Making your `struct` `CustomStringConvertible` and implementing `var description` allows you to format the output of the `struct` nicely.

You can then use [`max(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2294243-max) to find the `Student` with the largest `gpa` by passing a closure which defines how to compare two `Student` records.

```
struct Student: CustomStringConvertible {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var gpa: Double

    var description: String { return "\(firstName) \(lastName) (\(gpa))" }
}

let students: [Student] = [
    Student(firstName: "John", lastName: "Wilson", gpa: 2.4),
    Student(firstName: "Nancy", lastName: "Smith", gpa: 3.5),
    Student(firstName: "Michael", lastName: "Liu", gpa: 3.1)
]

if let student = students.max(by: { $0.gpa < $1.gpa }) {
    // Print the student information
    print(student)

    // Print the student's name
    print("\(student.firstName) \(student.lastName)")

    // Print the highest gpa
    print(student.gpa)
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Nancy Smith (3.5)
> Nancy Smith
> 3.5
> ```

---

**Alternate way to initialize `Student` data:**

As @LeoDabus suggested, you can use an array of tuples and `map()` to initialize your `students` array like this:

```
let students = [
    ("John", "Wilson", 2.4),
    ("Nancy", "Smith", 3.5),
    ("Michael", "Liu", 3.1)
].map(Student.init)
```

This has the advantage of eliminating visual clutter and saving typing at the cost of not explicitly showing which fields are being initialized.